# How to get form all element value in JSON before submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server, forms

I set my form name as `JSON` to get data in `JSON`. When I submit the HTML form to serve it is working fine but when I get data before submit then I am not able to get correct data.

All HTML render dynamic so there is not fix `x` and `y` values. This is the same demo.

```js
function validateData(){
 var isValidate = false;
 console.log($('form').serializeArray());
 console.log($('form').serialize());
 return isValidate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return validateData();" action="./send" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="a[x][Id]" value="hello x">
 <input type="radio" name="a[x][istest]" value="true"> Yes
 <input type="radio" name="a[x][istest]" value="false"> No
 <textarea name="a[x][msg]"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="a[y][Id]" value="hello y">
 <input type="radio" name="a[y][istest]" value="true"> Yes
 <input type="radio" name="a[y][istest]" value="false"> No
 <textarea name="a[y][msg]"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="hello form">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit "/>
</form>
```

I jQuery return following result

[image: JQuery Result]

When I check on server it is sending correct JSON

```
{ a:
   { x: { Id: 'hello x',istest : 'true', msg: '' },
     y: { Id: 'hello y',istest : 'false', msg: '' } },
  id: 'hello form' }
```

I did lots of searching but not able to get the correct answer.

Comment: I think you need to use a third party library like [$.serializeObject](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject) to achieve that.

Comment: @Mikey I cannot use third party lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I customized JSON and it returns same JSON to me that I want.

```
var formValues = $('form').serializeArray();

var formJSON = {};
formValues.map(function(index, value){
    var name = index.name;
    name = name.replace(/\[/g,',');
    name = name.replace(/\]/g,'');
    name = name.split(',');
    if(name.length == 3){
        if(formJSON[name[1]] != undefined)
            formJSON[name[1]][name[2]] = index.value;
        else
            formJSON[name[1]] = {[name[2]] :index.value};
    }
});

console.log(formJSON);
```